# change the start address of two linked lists with one function

Tags: c, linked-list

```
Cliente insert_last_adq(int option,Viagem global,Cliente adq,Cliente esp,int data,char *destino,int cod_destino,int id,char *nome){
/*FIX: Caso quando full*/
Cliente new_node = (Cliente) malloc( sizeof(Clientes_node) );
Cliente adq_orig = adq;
Cliente esp_orig = esp;
new_node->data=data;
new_node->cod_destino=cod_destino;
new_node->id=id;
strcpy(new_node->destino,destino);
strcpy(new_node->nome,nome);
switch( option ){
    case 0:
        if(adq==NULL){
            new_node->next=NULL;
            if(option==0){
                diminuir_disp(global,data,cod_destino);
            }
            return new_node;
        } else if( get_viagens_disp_destino(global,data,cod_destino) > 0 ){
            while(adq->next!=NULL){
                adq=adq->next;
            }
            adq->next=new_node;
            new_node->next=NULL;
            diminuir_disp(global,data,cod_destino);
            return adq_orig;
        } else if( get_viagens_disp_destino(global,data,cod_destino)==0 ){
            /*FIX: Not workin*/
            if(esp==NULL){
                new_node->next=NULL;
                esp=new_node;
            }else{
                while(esp->next!=NULL){
                    esp=esp->next;
                }
                esp->next=new_node;
                new_node->next=NULL;
                return adq_orig;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if(esp==NULL){
                new_node->next=NULL;
                return new_node;
            }else{
                while(esp->next!=NULL){
                    esp=esp->next;
                }
                esp->next=new_node;
                new_node->next=NULL;
                return esp_orig;
            }
        break;
}
```

}

After the comment FIX: Not working, I have the line:

```
esp=new_node;
```

So my objective was to give the start address of the linked list esp the address of new_node.
I know i can change this when if i return an address but the prob is that the adq linked list will be the one recieving the return value.

Btw esp is a pointed to the struct, as well as adq, so no "*" required.
And adq and esp are of the same type "Cliente"

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef, as apparently you are doing with type `Cliente`.

Comment: ...and if you must, at least use the Hungarian notation such as `pCliente` to make the code easier to follow.

Comment: Then how can i initialize adq to NULL?

Comment: To "initialize adq to NULL" --> `Cliente_as_a_non_pointer_type *adq = NULL;`

Comment: Don't cast the result returned from `malloc()`. It's not necessary in C, and can hide the failure to include the required function prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a integer in the params. and i set it to 0 or 1 depending on wut list i want to set the return value as. Then out the function I just used:

```
if(out_int==0){
    adq=return_pCliente;
}else if(out_int==1){
    esp=return_pCliente;
}
```

The out_int is passed in the params of the function as int *out_int, so it can be changed inside the function.
No changes were required in the rest of the code. I am on the clock so tmy solution works just fine. But thanks for the help, learned one or two new things.